# Why does C# not calculate my equation in the right order?

Tags: c#, equation

I have been messing around with some dynamic math equations. I wrote it all in one line since you can't write advanced multiline equations in console applications.

I wanted to write this is one-line code in C#:

[image: This is what i wrote in my calculator]

And this is what i wrote in C#:

```
double result;
result = Math.Sqrt(10.39230485 / (0.25 * Math.Tan(720D / (2D * 6D)) * 6D));
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

But when I ran this code it gave me 4.652730... when it should have been exactly 2.

What did i do wrong in this equation (if anything)?

Comment: before anything don't put result between " " it is not a string value.

Comment: *when it should have been exactly 2.* After you've fixed the angle problem, don't be surprised when it's not *exactly* 2 either. I get `2.00000000044136`

Comment: @MattBurland What do you mean by the angle problem? what is the mistake?

Comment: As in ArgusMagnus' answer

Comment: @TheFoxOnFire Do not edit your question to add the solution that worked.  Accept the answer below (by clicking the checkmark) that worked for you, instead.

Comment: @MattBurland Also note that the numerator `10.39230485` looks like something that has been rounded to ten figures. If you take the numerator to be exactly six times the square root of three (`6*sqrt(3)`), and see 720 as 720° (so 720 _degrees_), then the equality becomes exact mathematically. Of course when you use `double`, it may not be exact in the computer, but it should be correct to about 15 places as we expect for `double`.

Answer (score 13):

`Math.Tan()` function takes the angle in radians, not degrees.

Multiply the argument by `Math.Pi/180` to convert degrees to radians.